# Serial communication with Arduino UNO and Mac using bluetooth mate

Tags: macos, bluetooth, arduino, serial-communication

I'm trying to set up serial communication between Arduino and Mac via Bluetooth and have a problem.

My environment is that:

- Arduino UNO
- Bluetooth Mate from sparkfun
- MacBook, OS X 10.7

First, I programmed arduino like below, as it shown in [this tutorial](http://bit.ly/KxhvfT).

```
/***********************
 Bluetooth test program
***********************/

int counter = 0;
int incomingByte;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // see if there's incoming serial data:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the oldest byte in the serial buffer:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
    // if it's a capital R, reset the counter
    if (incomingByte == 'R') {
      Serial.println("RESET");
      counter=0;
    }
  }

  Serial.println(counter);
  counter++;

  delay(250);
}
```

It worked nicely when Arduino was wired with USB. (Arduino console receive the sequence of numbers, like 1, 2, 3, 4... with line breaks.)

Then I connected Arduino UNO and Bluetooth Mate with some wires, and got it successfully paired with Mac.

When I run this line on iTerm, I only received the sequence of question marks.

```
$ sudo cu -s 115200 -l /dev/tty.name-of-port
Connected.
??????????????????????????????
```

I also tried `screen /dev/tty.name-of-port`, or Arduino console, but the result is the all same.

How can I solve these garbled signals and receive correct chars?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post about how you have connected UNO and Bluetooth mate?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's because of the high baudrate. Try reducing it to 9600. I have a feeling that 115200 is too much for the serial connection.